# I'm not able to import my model class into serializer file

Tags: django, django-models, import, django-rest-framework

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_slack.views import DRSEventView, DRSCommandView
from django.urls import path


api_patterns = ([
        path('web/', DRSEventView.as_view()),
        path('events/', DRSCommandView.as_view()),
    ], 'api')


urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('api/v1/', include(api_patterns)),]
```

Now what's happening is I'm using django 1.9 which doesn't let me include django.urls. Second thing If I use any other version of djangorestframework it doesn't let me use path object in this.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I'm not able to import model classes in this file"? Do you get an error of some sort?

Comment: Yes please look at code again and tell me where I've gone wrong. If you haven't understanding something please ask

Comment: Thanks for adding some more info to the question. What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.9

Comment: `django.urls` was added in Django 2.0, this is why you are getting that error. If possible I'd suggest updating to the latest version of Django.

Comment: Yeah but I'm not using django.urls in my urls.py file.

Comment: If I change the version I have to change other dependencies also.

Comment: Well, looking at the traceback it would appear that you are using a version of DRF that uses `django.urls`. Either use an older version of DRF or update your version of Django.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: what if I make a urls.py in a local app not in the global file?

Comment: That is a no go. Django will try and load each app's `url.py` file. Like @JamieWilliams said, you either upgrade Django or downgrade DRF.

Comment: so what do you think which DRF version I should use? @foobarna

Comment: Looking at the changelogs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#370 something before `3.7.0`, so... a `3.6.x` version would be good.

Comment: djangorestframework==3.9.2
Is what I'm using right now

Comment: Hey it worked but now i'm not able to import path in that. Any idea how to do that? @foobarna

Comment: What path do you mean?

Comment: Now I've updated it please check and tell me if I can change something in this? or how do I rewrite a program. Right now I'm using djangorestframework 3.6.4